# Is there any build queue, or some way to switch production without wasting hammers?

Tags: civilization-6

As an avid “stuff those few extra turns' production, until my next research is complete, into something I'll want to complete later” in Civ V; but I can find no ‘show queue’ button in Civ VI!

Is my production just wasted, if I switch targets?

Comment: See https://github.com/kblease/ProductionQueue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 years later...

There is a queue in Civilization 6 now. It also allows to rearrange items in the build queue. As noted in another answer, the production is not lost however when switching production targets and using the production queue only has the effect of automatically selecting the next production target.

[image]

Answer (score 24):

As far as I can tell, there is, sadly, not a build queue available in Civ VI.

However, I can confirm that switching production does not reset your progress. I worked on a Builder for a few turns, then switched. After finishing the latter target and going back to choose production, I had the same production applied to a Builder, and was able to complete it from where I had left off.

Something to note: When building a District of any kind, the destination tile for that District is set whenever you confirm its placement. Changing production targets, then switching back to the District will not allow you to change the destination tile for that District.

Source: Anecdotal gameplay experience

Comment: Honestly, I've found this easy to abuse: produce most of a powerful unit in several of my cities, but leave it incomplete; when I get surprise-war'd, drop a collection of invisible powerful units on them in a single turn … also, it's *amazing* with the Venetian Armory wonder — I “held back” basically an entire era's worth of production, and suddenly popped a fleet of 12 Caravels and Privateers. :P

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a UI bug, but production might carry over. I've had times where I complete something, start the next item, and it takes one or two turns less than indicated in the build menu. I always assumed this was carry-over production, but can't confirm.

Comment: surprise war'd +1

Comment: I just saw on Twitch someone using a production queue - is it a mod?

Comment: Has this been added with the patch 1.0.1 - if so how do you use it?

Comment: Can you explain about the surprise war thing?

Answer (score 6):

There is no show queue in Civ, which makes me sad because I abused that feature in Civ V.

However, just like Civ 5, you won't lose the production you put into things, and Civ 6 actually SHOWS this a bit better by showing a progress bar on things you'd previously started.